# IdP server over spring boot SSO

Tags: java, spring-boot, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, idp

I'm trying to implement my own IdP on Spring boot. I followed the documentation of Spring security SAML to give me a clear idea but there are no good examples of this. The only part I found is

> You can test IDP initialized single sign-on with URL https://idp.ssocircle.com:443/sso/saml2/jsp/idpSSOInit.jsp?metaAlias=/ssocircle&spEntityID=replaceWithUniqueIdentifier, after replacing the service provider identifier with the one configured as entityId in your securityContext.xml. It is possible to provide relayState data sent to your SP with parameter RelayState.

But this example bases on ssocircle is the IdP and the sample Java project is the SP. So I can't see any of the ssocircle configurations (what endpoints I need and other configs) and really can't find any good example of this. In some part I read that with the Spring security SAML dependency I can make my application act as an IdP, then I reread the full document I noticed this

> This chapter provides essential information needed to enable your application to act as a service provider and interact with identity providers using SAML 2.0 protocol. Later in this guide you can find information about detailed configuration options and additional use-cases enabled by this component.

Basically, this document does not cover what I'm trying to do, and right now I don't even know if this dependency will help me to reach my goal or I will need to move to another library like Shibboleth project. Have you faced this issue before?